# Problems with ValidatorConstraint in Symfony 2.5

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

after upgrading from Symfony 2.4 to 2.5 my form validator constraints are not working any more.

I get: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\Type\FormTypeValidatorExtension::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator given, defined in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Validator/Type/FormTypeValidatorExtension.php on line 36

Anybody has a suggestion how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the validation api in your config.yml.

Comment from the UPGRADE-2.5.md 
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.5.md

"The validation engine in `Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator` was replaced
   by a new one in `Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator`.
   With that change, several classes were deprecated that will be removed in
   Symfony 3.0. Also, the API of the validator was slightly changed. More
   details about that can be found in UPGRADE-3.0.

You can choose the desired API via the new "api" entry in
   app/config/config.yml:"

`framework:
       validation:
           enabled: true
           api: auto`

Comment: setting the api to either "auto" or "2.4" fixed my issue. Thanx