# Symfony Unit Test Form Extension Mock

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, composer-php

Before updating my code via composer my forms unit test was working. It is now failing on the extension mock.
Heres the error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\Type\FormTypeValidatorExtension::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorInterface, instance of Mock_ValidatorInterface_14b95ba0 given
```

Heres my composer required section:

```
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.3",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bridge": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~2.3"
   }
```

Heres the validation mock in the unit test setup method:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Forms;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\Type\FormTypeValidatorExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationList;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\CoreExtension;

class TestedTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{

protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $validator = $this->getMock('\Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface');
    $validator->method('validate')->will($this->returnValue(new ConstraintViolationList()));
    $formTypeExtension = new FormTypeValidatorExtension($validator);
    $coreExtension = new CoreExtension();

    $this->factory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
            ->addExtensions($this->getExtensions())
            ->addExtension($coreExtension)
            ->addTypeExtension($formTypeExtension)
            ->getFormFactory();
}
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong with the mock? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: must be an instance of \Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorInterface" vs "\Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface" You appear to have too many 'Validator' in the mock.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with ValidatorConstraint in Symfony 2.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009719/problems-with-validatorconstraint-in-symfony-2-5)

Comment: @AlisterBulman Yes this was exactly it. Removing the second Validator worked. Im using Symphony ~2.3 and not  2.5 so the deprecation of Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 2):

From UPGRADE-2.5.md:

> The validation engine in `Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator` was
>   replaced by a new one in
>   `Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator`. With that
>   change, several classes were deprecated that will be removed in
>   Symfony 3.0. Also, the API of the validator was slightly changed. More
>   details about that can be found in UPGRADE-3.0.

And here is similar problem:
[Problems with ValidatorConstraint in Symfony 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009719/problems-with-validatorconstraint-in-symfony-2-5)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the backslashes to use them in a string:

`$validator = $this->getMock('\\Symfony\\Component\\Validator\\Validator\\ValidatorInterface');`